# I couldn't get antler_test.java to compile

Tags: java, antlr4

```
` import org.anltr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.anltr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

public class antlr_test{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
   ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
    exprLexer lexer = new exprLexer(input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
     exprParser parser = new exprParser(tokens);
    parser.prog();
  }
}`

`error: package org.anltr.v4.runtime does not exist
import org.anltr.v4.runtime.*;
^
antlr_test.java:3: error: package org.anltr.v4.runtime.tree does not exist
import org.anltr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
^
antlr_test.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
^
symbol:   class ANTLRInputStream
location: class antlr_test
antlr_test.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
                             ^
symbol:   class ANTLRInputStream
location: class antlr_test
antlr_test.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    ^
```

symbol:   class CommonTokenStream
   location: class antlr_test
   antlr_test.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
                                       ^
   symbol:   class CommonTokenStream
   location: class antlr_test
   antlr_test.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        parser.prog();
              ^
   symbol:   method prog()
   location: variable parser of type exprParser
   7 errors`

Comment: Figured it out nevermind

Comment: Good to hear you solved it! Feel free to delete your question, or answer it yourself.